# Let $\Gamma$ be discrete in S. Then for any region $Ω$ in $S$, $Ω \cap \Gamma$ is discrete in Ω

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation

I'm trying to understand this existence of triangulation's proof in this [book](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~ars/diffch8.pdf).
I have problems to understand the lemma 8.2.6:

**Let $\Gamma$ be discrete in S. Then for any region $Ω$ in $S$, $Ω \cap \Gamma$ is
discrete in Ω**

I didn't understand why this $\gamma$ in the proof exists.

I need help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Gamma\cap\Omega$ is a *different set of curves* than $\Gamma$.  One curve in $\Gamma$ could become many curves in $\Gamma\cap\Omega$.  This is how we find $\gamma$.

More specifically, we have a point $x$ with a neighborhood $U$ (guaranteed by discreteness of $\Gamma$ in $S$) that meets only finitely many curves in $\Gamma$, but (by assumption toward contradiction) meets *infinitely* many curves in $\Gamma\cap\Omega$.  Since each curve in $\Gamma\cap\Omega$ comes from some curve in $\Gamma$, there must be a curve in $\Gamma$ which induces infinitely many curves in $\Gamma\cap\Omega$.  This curve is $\gamma$.

Comment: yes, thank you very much, now everything's clear :D

Comment: Glad to hear it's clear - you're quite welcome! :)

Comment: Look at $\gamma^{-1}\Omega$ and $\gamma^{-1}U$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  Each should have countably many connected components.  Pick a point from each.

Comment: what do you mean by $\gamma^{-1}\Omega$ $\gamma^{-1}U$?

Comment: Since $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to S$, we can look at the inverse images of $U$ and $\Omega$ under $\gamma$.

Comment: why $\gamma^{-1}(\Omega)$ and $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ should have countably many connected components? $U$  and $\Omega$ are connected?

Comment: It should be clear from the fact that $\gamma$ intersects $\Omega$ infinitely many times.  Tell you what - make your follow-up questions more precise and edit them into the original question, and (if I have time) edit clarifications into my answer.  Sound good?

Comment: yes, thank you very much